# Paper.js change layer coordinate start point

Tags: javascript, paperjs

everyone.

It is possible in paper.js change layer start coordinate position from top-left corner? 
Use case: I put image into bottom layer and draw some stuff on top layer. Image can be scalled and moved. I need to get my drawing path points coord in image coordinate system.  And I want to set my drawing layer coordinate start to image top left point and move it then image scale/move.

I try do this:

```
var layer = new Layer();
project.activeLayer.setName("DrawingStuff");
project.activeLayer.setPosition(paperjs.project.view.center);
project.activeLayer.bounds.x = 300;
project.activeLayer.bounds.y = 300;
project.activeLayer.bounds.width = raster.width;
project.activeLayer.bounds.height = raster.height;
```

But it is don't work. Name is setted, but bounds and position still empty.

Will be very thankfull for any advise.

P.S. I know that I can just recalculate path point from canvas coords system to image coords system, but I want to try change layer coords start point

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use the current coordinate system and change the `zoom` and `center` properties of the project's `view`.  Take a look at the code behind the zoom tool in main.js at http://sketch.paperjs.org:

```
var lastPoint;
var body = $('body');
zoomTool = new Tool({
    buttonClass: 'icon-zoom'
}).on({
    mousedown: function(event) {
        if (event.modifiers.space) {
            lastPoint = paper.view.projectToView(event.point);
            return;
        }
        var factor = 1.25;
        if (event.modifiers.option)
            factor = 1 / factor;
        paper.view.zoom *= factor;
        paper.view.center = event.point;
    },

    ...

    mousedrag: function(event) {
        if (event.modifiers.space) {
            body.addClass('zoom-grab');
            // In order to have coordinate changes not mess up the
            // dragging, we need to convert coordinates to view space,
            // and then back to project space after the view space has
            // changed.
            var point = paper.view.projectToView(event.point),
                last = paper.view.viewToProject(lastPoint);
            paper.view.scrollBy(last.subtract(event.point));
            lastPoint = point;
        }
    },
    ...
});
```